# SharePoint Content Rating, can I modify the 5 rating stars into 1 star

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, rating, content-rating

I am using sp 2010. I would like to use the rating functionality. But I would like to remove star 2 till 5. So it is only possible to click on the first star or leave it. Something like the "LIKE" functionality. You can like ot or not. Something with jQuery?

Or is there some other functionality to like or unlike an item. But which also has report functionality to show the results of the rating.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In SharePoint 2010 you have only one options while if you are using SharePoint 2013 then you will get 2 options OOTB.

- Star Ratings
- Like

read this for SharePoint 2013. http://sharepoint.sureshc.com/2012/08/changes-in-rating-in-sharepoint-2013.html

Comment: nice to know for in the future, but now I need a solution for in sp 2010 :) Do you know some solution?